# List comprehension vs zipWith in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is code #1:

```
fibs = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

I wrote the same code with list comprehension (code #2):

```
fibs' = 0:1:[x+y|x<-fibs',y<-tail fibs']
```

but code #1 produces the Fibonnacci numbers while code #2 produces `0 1 1 1 1`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List comprehensions such as `[x+y|x<-fibs',y<-tail fibs']` will generate `x+y` for *all* combinations of `x,y` extracted from the two lists. For instance,

```
[ (x,y) | x<-[1..10] , y<-[1..10] ]
```

will generate all the 100 pairs, essentially computing the cartesian product of the two lists.
Zipping the lists instead only generates pairs for the corresponding elements, yielding only 10 pairs.

[Parallel list comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#parallel-list-comprehensions) instead work as `zip` does. For instance,

```
[ (x,y) | x<-[1..10] | y<-[1..10] ]
```

will return the same 10 pairs as `zip`. You can enable this Haskell extension by adding `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}` at the beginning of your file.

Personally, I do not use this extension much, preferring to explicitly use `zip` instead.

Comment: It may also help to unpack the list comprehension into functions calls: [(x,y) | x<-[1..10], y <- [1..10]] = concatMap (\x -> [(x,y) | y <-[1..10]]) [1..10] = concatMap (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y)) [1..10]) [1..10]

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions over multiple lists do not work like `zip`/`zipWith` - each element of one list is combined with each element of the other list rather than being combined pair-wise. To illustrate this difference, look at this simpler example:

```
xs = [1,2]
ys = [3, 4]
zipped = zipWith (+) xs ys -- [4, 6]
comprehended = [x+y | x <- xs, y <- ys] [4, 5, 5, 6]
```

To get the behavior of `zip` in a list comprehension, you'd need to use the GHC extension for parallel list comprehensions, which allows you to write this:

```
parallelComp = [x+y | x <- xs | y <- ys] -- [4, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is: it's not the same code. :) The first sample uses `zipWith` which is applying `(+)` pairwise. The second one does something like [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), but instead of returning pair `(x,y)` it returns `x+y`.

Compare:

```
zip [1..5] [2..6] === [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)]
```

With:

```
[ (x,y) | x <- [1..5], y <- [2..6] ] === [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),
                                          (2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),
                                          (3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),
                                          (4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),
                                          (5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(5,6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension

```
[ x + y | x <- xs, y <- ys ]
```

equals (more or less) to the following imperative pseudocode

```
list = emptyList
foreach (x in xs) {
    foreach (y in ys) {
        append (x+y) to list
    }
}
return list
```

However, if that `ys` is an infinitive list, as in your code #2, then the result `list` will be

```
list = emptyList
x = head of xs
foreach (y in ys) {
    append (x+y) to list
}
return list
```

That is why you got that list consists of 0, 1, 1, ... .

Answer (score 1):

You can get the behaviour you want using `ZipList` rather than `[]`.  Since `ZipList` is not a monad you cannot use monadic `do`.  Instead you have to use applicative `do`, also known as "arrow notation"! :)

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Category

data A f a b = A (f (a -> b))
type Arr f a = A f () a

runA :: A f a b -> f (a -> b)
runA (A f) = f

arrOfApp :: Functor f => f a -> Arr f a
arrOfApp = A . fmap const

appOfArr :: Functor f => Arr f a -> f a
appOfArr = fmap ($ ()) . runA
```

The definitions above are rather similar to those you can find in [optparse-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.6.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Arrows.html).

```
zipListArr :: [a] -> Arr ZipList a
zipListArr = arrOfApp . ZipList

getZipListArr :: Arr ZipList a -> [a]
getZipListArr = getZipList . appOfArr

instance Applicative f => Category (A f) where
  id = A (pure id)
  A f . A g = A ((.) <$> f <*> g)

instance Applicative f => Arrow (A f) where
  arr f = A (pure f)
  first (A f) = A (fmap first f)

fibs' :: [Int]
fibs' = 0 : 1 : (getZipListArr $ proc () -> do
  x <- zipListArr fibs' -< ()
  y <- zipListArr (tail fibs') -< ()
  returnA -< x + y)

*Main> take 10 fibs'
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```